# php settting $_GET value

Tags: php, http-headers, get, request

I need to set the $_GET values; can I do this?

ie I have an empty $_GET array. How can make it nonempty with php?

Maybe with help of http headers?

Thank you in advance;

Comment: Do you mean pass data into the `$_GET` variable via a http request?

Comment: @Wolfy87. Yes. I have an empty $_GET array. How can make it nonempty with php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is three ways of doing this.

One:

```
<form method="get" action="file.php">
<input type="text" name="TextThing" />
</form>
```

In the php file:

```
$_GET["TextThing"]; //contains the text of the texbox TextThing...
```

Second:

Use a questionmark behind the url, like this:
http://domain.com/file.php?foo=bar&stack=overflow

Then:

```
$_GET["foo"]; //contains bar
$_GET["stack"]; //contains overflow
```

Remember that your users easily can change the values of the variables.

Third:

```
$_GET["foo"] = "bar";
$_GET["foo"]; //contains bar
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is populated with the params/values sent in the querystring of the url, so if you call `http://example.com/my.php?foo=bar&foo2=baz` then in my.php `$_GET['foo'] => 'bar'` and `$_GET['foo2'] => 'baz'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating $_GET

```
$_GET['test'] = 'abc';
```

And then redirect users there:

```
header('Location: ?' . http_build_query($_GET));
```

You just have to make sure to redirect only when necessary, so that you don't take users into infinite redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_GET` array is initially populated from the query string, but you can overwrite that if you want to without redirecting. If at some point in your code you set `$_GET['foo'] = 'bar';` then that is set thereafter, no matter what the query string is.

Comment: (But I wouldn't recommend it.)